# Merge/synonymize [facebook-ar-studio] and [spark-ar-studio]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [facebook-ar-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ar-studio) and [spark-ar-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-ar-studio) both refer to the same thing.

[spark-ar-studio](https://sparkar.com/ar-studio) is a powerful tool designed to make stunning interactive experiences for the Facebook camera, create interactive augmented reality experiences with or without code, and then share what you build with the world.

I'd suggest them being merged or turned into synonyms. As for which one to keep, I'd suggest choosing `spark-ar-studio` as mentioned on the [official web site](https://sparkar.com/ar-studio).